Why does Django use WSGI instead of CGI for web applications?
Is using wsgi similar with how cgi was used in django web deveelopment? and are there web developers that are using the latest version of python to build web app as it doesn't support CGI
I was learning django by building a web app but I couldn't get CGI components cause I was using the latest python version update and WSGI was recommended to me.

Running a Python interpreter, especially Django for each requests, introduces a ton of overhead: already loading the models, etc. often takes a few deciseconds, so it would slow down the process.
